# Sphinx auto documenting module variables

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx to document a python module that is essentially a series of variable assignments.  Specifically, they are lists of RGB codes generated by seaborn for use with seaborn and matplotlib.  For example:

```
import seaborn as sns

#: List of RGB tuples for 10 color palette
PRIMARY_10 = sns.color_palette(['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000'])

#: List of RGB tuples for 5 color palette
PRIMARY_5 = sns.color_palette(['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000'])
```

The following works, but it's not exactly what I want:

```
color_palettes
==============
.. automodule:: cy.basics.color_palettes
   :members:
```

It generates a page that looks likes:

```
color_palettes

cy.basics.color_palettes.PRIMARY_10 = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
List of RGB tuples for 10 >color palette 

cy.basics.color_palettes.PRIMARY_5 = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)] 
List of RGB tuples for 5 color palette
```

I would like the documentation to omit the right-hand side to the assignment, i.e., the long list of tuples.  I would also like to include an image of the color pallet beneath each.  I thought I could do this as follows:

```
color_palettes
==============
.. automodule:: cy.basics.color_palettes
    .. autodata:: PRIMARY_10 
        :annotation:
        .. image:: primary-10.png
    .. autodata:: PRIMARY_5
        :annotation:
        .. image:: primary-5.png
```

The result is close, but it omits by description of the variable and uses the description of seaborn color_palatte.  See below:

```
color_palettes

cy.basics.color_palettes.PRIMARY_10
Set the color palette in a with statement, otherwise be a list.
../_images/primary-10.png

cy.basics.color_palettes.PRIMARY_5
Set the color palette in a with statement, otherwise be a list.
../_images/primary-5.png
```

This is the result whether I use the comment format with #: or a docstring.  What is the right way of doing this in Sphinx.

Example below of what I want:

```
color_palettes

cy.basics.color_palettes.PRIMARY_10
List of RGB tuples for 10 color palette
../_images/primary-10.png

cy.basics.color_palettes.PRIMARY_5
List of RGB tuples for 5 color palette
../_images/primary-5.png
```

Comment: `autodata` picks up the docstring from the `seaborn.palettes._ColorPalette` class instead of your docstrings for `PRIMARY_5` and `PRIMARY_10`. This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: thanks mzjn, I was hoping someone would come along with an answer, but looks like maybe I should submit a bug report

Comment: You can to use `.. literalinclude:: `, it literally puts the code as text in your html page. You can look in [this example documentation](https://dalyag.github.io/Sphinx185/conf.html) to see how the result might look.